# Accessing private variable in PHP's code

Tags: php

Why doesn't the following output the data I'm expecting?

```
class student
{
    private $name;
    private $id;

    public function _construct($name,$id)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->id = $id; 
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getID ()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
$mhs = new student("budi","152012102");

echo "name = ".$mhs->getName();
```

I don't know what's happening, help?

Comment: name=$nama; whats your nama boy?

Comment: oh that just a TYPO ,AFTER I FIX IT, IT STILL DOESN'T OUTPUT THE 'name'

Comment: helo, u can test the the code here http://writecodeonline.com/php/ , or in your IDE , it just doesnt output the 'name'

Comment: Also `_construct` should be `__construct`

Comment: @febri23: DON'T SHOUT, WE CAN READ LOWER-CASE LETTERS, TOO. And while all upper-case comments aren't considered _good form_, a class name _should_ start with an UpperCase, and the rest of the name is CamelCased... just so you know: http://www.php-fig.org

Comment: OH YEAH , THATS IT , THANKS Harri, and thx also guys..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems:

### 1) Calling the constructor

When you call the constructor, you need to prefix it with TWO underscores.

So in full, you constructor should be:

```
public function __construct($name, $id)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->id = $id;
}
```

### 2) Typo

There also seems to be a simple typo in your constructor:

You're assigning `$nama` instead of `$name`

`$this->name = $nama;`

This should be

`$this->name = $name;`

**[EDIT]** This typo seems to be fixed in the main question now

Comment: oh that just a TYPO ,AFTER I FIX IT, IT STILL DOESN'T OUTPUT THE 'name'

Comment: Why is this wrong answer upvoted? You cant access private variables like that.

Comment: so how should i access the private variable ??

Comment: @YUNOWORK it's in the constructor, the answer is correct...the code should output the desired string

Comment: noticed another issue with the constructor, modified my answer (see section 1)

Comment: y sry my mistake. Im a retard.^^ You need __construct btw, not _construct.

Comment: yes I got it , thanks guys , my book does't even discuss this '__' thing, i should throw the book away and ask money back , LOL.

Comment: don't worry, I've been working with PHP for a decade, and little things like this always trip me up! If the answer above was correct, please hit the tick icon ;)